# Ember js state handling

Tags: ember.js

I'm really new to Ember and I have some problems and questions.

I use this function to get the informations from a single table row

```
click: function(e) {
   var element = $(e.target).closest("td");  
   App.person = element.text().trim();
   var router;
   router = this.get('controller.target.router');
   router.transitionTo('newRoute');
   }
```

I've bound the variable `Person` to a text field:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="App.Person"}}
```

When I click on the table element it transitions to `newRoute` and fills the text field with the selected entry. But when I click on the table again nothing nothing happens.

What I want is to dynamically change the content of the textfield.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to dynamically change the content of the textfield, there is no need for a router transition. Also things will be much easier if you bind fields to the default context (the controller) instead of using global variables like `App.person`.

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="person"}}
```

Then in your click fx, you can modify the value:

```
click: function(e) {
  text = this.get('controller.person');
  this.set('controller.person', text.trim();
}
```

Some other things to be aware of:

- Avoid global references such as `App.person` whenever possible. The framework should be giving you access to everything you need via local variables. The way you accessed the controller from your click fx is an example of doing things *the ember way*. If you can't figure out a way to do something without a global reference, ask for help here on StackOverflow.
- Try to avoid accessing model data thru DOM elements like `$(e.target).closest("td");`
- In cases where you really do need to kick off a transition from view code, no need to access the router. Assuming you are using latest ember you can call `this.get('controller').transitionTo('newRoute')`